# IPC Cannot Find the File Specified

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ipc, remoting

using IPC over local TCP to communicate from Client to a Server thread.  The connection itself doesn't seem to be throwing any errors, but every time I try to make one of the associated calls, I get this message:

`System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Could not connect to an IPC Port: The System cannot Find the file specified`

What I am attempting to figure out is WHY.  Because this WAS working correctly, until I transitioned the projects in question (yes, both) from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0.

**Listen Code**

```
private void ThreadListen()
{
  _listenerThread = new Thread(Listen) {Name = "Listener Thread", Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal};
  _listenerThread.Start();
}

private void Listen()
{
  _listener = new Listener(this);

  LifetimeServices.LeaseTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);      

  IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
  props["port"] = 63726;
  props["name"] = "AGENT";

  TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(props, null, null);
  ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

  RemotingServices.Marshal(_listener, "Agent");
  Logger.WriteLog(new LogMessage(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "Now Listening for commands..."));
  LogEvent("Now Listening for commands...");
}
```

**Selected Client Code**

```
private void InitializeAgent()
{
  try
  {
     _agentController =
     (IAgent)RemotingServices.Connect(typeof(IAgent), IPC_URL);
     //Note: IPC_URL was originally "ipc://AGENT/AGENT"  
     //      It has been changed to read "tcp://localhost:63726/Agent"
     SetAgentPid();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    HandleError("Unable to initialize the connected agent.", 3850244, ex);
  }
}

//This is the method that throws the error
public override void LoadTimer()
{
  // first check to see if we have already set the agent process id and set it if not
  if (_agentPid < 0) 
  {
    SetAgentPid();
  }

  try
  {
    TryStart();
    var tries = 0;
    while (tries < RUNCHECK_TRYCOUNT)
    {
      try
      {
        _agentController.ReloadSettings();//<---Error occurs here
        return;
      } catch (RemotingException)
      {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        tries++;
        if (tries == RUNCHECK_TRYCOUNT)
        throw;
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    HandleError("Unable to reload the timer for the connected agent.", 3850243, ex);
  }
}
```

If you need to see something I haven't shown, please ask, I'm pretty much flying blind here.

**Edit:** I think the issue is the `IPC_URL` String.  It is currently set to `"ipc://AGENT/AGENT"`.  The thing is, I have no idea where that came from, why it worked before, or what might be stopping it from working now.

***Update***

I was able to get the IPC Calls working correctly by changing the IPC_URL String, but I still lack understanding of why what I did worked.  Or rather, why the original code stopped working and I needed to change it in the first place.

The string I am using now is `"tcp://localhost:63726/Agent"`

Can anyone tell me, not why the new string works, I know that...but *Why did the original string work before and why did updating the project target to .NET 4.0 break it?*

Comment: Are you using a third party software? I've seen this a lot when the service stops running. like [link] (http://www.copadata.com/forums/showthread.php?p=11103) here.

Comment: Actually, its my own software, that's why I have the server side code listed as well, I have both projects...although I didn't actually write either one of them.  I'm attempting to avoid having to completely re-write the IPC between the two into something that I can actually understand/use....but if I dont have a choice then I do what I have to

Comment: I think the Issue is the ICP_URL.  it is currently `"ipc://AGENT/AGENT"`.  I dont know where that came from or why it was working and why it might have broken.

Comment: @Nevyn Did the listen code always use a 'TcpChannel'? This should be an 'IpcServerChannel' if you really want to use IPC. Then there is no need for a port number as you specify a name for the pipe, AGENT in your case.

Comment: As far as I can tell looking through the source control history, it has always been a TcpChannel...Which Is why I was so confused that the "ipc://..." string was working, but I also have proof that it IS working (Current prod uses it unchanged)...so...yea...